# Use different versions of OpenSSL

Tags: g++, openssl

i'm working on ubuntu, and i'm developing a C++ library that uses OpenSSL.

So, the PC i use to develop the code has an OpenSSL version of 2010. I create the lib,  compile it with a simple test program, and i execute it successfully.

Then, when i test the lib in other PC (which have the latest OpenSSL version - May 2012), i compile the simple test program successfully, but when i execute it they crashes.

I "solved" the problem updating the version of OpenSSL from 2010 to the last , but in future it is possible that this problem can occur again, if someone will use the lib with a recent OpenSSL version.

So, i would like to know if there is a possibility of, for example, create the lib with  the OpenSSL necessary files, in order to the code execute regardless of the OpenSSL version of the PC that is compiling the lib with the simple test program.

For creating my lib, i compile my files into .obj files (for example: g++ -c fileA.c -o fileA.o), and then i create a libABC.a file (ar rcs libABC.a filaA.o fileB.o ...).
I only use the "-lssl" compile option to link my library with the rest of the code, for example: g++ simpleCode.o libABC.a -o Test -lssl

Best Regards,
   Sérgio

Comment: You can compile with -static, but it will increase the size of the executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally problems like this are solved by giving incompatible versions of the library a different soname (e.g. libssl.0.9.7 vs libssl.1.0.0). If your version of libssl.so doesn't have a versioned soname it is broken.

To check the library's soname, and the soname your program is linked with, execute these commands

```
 ldd /path/to/your/program/Test | grep openssl
 objdump --private-headers /usr/lib/libssl.so* | grep SONAME
```

If your program is linked with libssl.0.9.7 it will simply not start with any other version.